# Ater Increasing sleep() fd not working properly

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am doing linux serial port programming and reading and writing messages to and from fd regularly after some delay . when the delay is less then 5( sleep 5)) seconds my port works properly very infinite time but when i increase the delay time ( sleep (20) or more then 10 seconds ) my fd stops working after 2-3 cycles of messages . can you guys tell me why this kind of behaviour. have tried giving delay in many other ways as well but still the same.
below is my code snippet

```
struct termios port_settings;
int fd;
unsigned char msgR[10];

fd = open(PORT,O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_SYNC);
if(fd == -1)
{
    printf("Failed to open PORT: %s  \n\n",PORT);
    perror("Error:");
    printf("\n\nunable to open port...\n\n========================\n\n");

}

bzero(&port_settings, sizeof(port_settings));
cfsetispeed(&port_settings, BAUDRATE);
cfsetospeed(&port_settings, BAUDRATE);

port_settings.c_cflag = (port_settings.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;
port_settings.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;
port_settings.c_lflag = 0;

port_settings.c_oflag = 0;
port_settings.c_cc[VMIN]  =10;
port_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;

port_settings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

port_settings.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

port_settings.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
port_settings.c_cflag |= 0;
port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);

while(1)
{
    sleep(20); //time for betting for 1st client

    write (fd,STATUS,5);


    int n = read (fd, &msgR, sizeof(msgR));
    if(n ==10)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of Bytes Read is-%d||MSG Recived : %s\n",n,msgR);
        process(fd,msgR);
    }
    else
        perror("Error while READ:");

}
```

this is just a rough code to show the configurations i am using ..please help

Comment: Learn about multiplexing polling syscalls like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).  Read [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Use `memset`, not `bzero`

Comment: Don't use `memset` or `bzero`; use `tcgetattr()`.  Use proper serial port configuration: [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).  Your read  request has a bogus buffer address: `read (fd, &msgR, sizeof(msgR))` -- `msgR` is already the address of the array.  Is the `printf()` after the read actually indicating good input?  `read(fd, msgR, sizeof(msgR))` should work.  You should also learn to properly test the return code from each and every syscall.

Comment: you mean the problem is all because of improper configuration of port or fd

Comment: *"you mean the problem is all because..."* -- No, I mentioned two (2) more major problems (besides the port configuration) of your code that needs fixing. There are other numerous less-severe bugs in your code.

Comment: will correct those..can increased sleep cause this kind of behaviour

Comment: *"can increased sleep cause this kind of behaviour"* -- Highly unlikely, especially if the connected device only sends data in response to the `write()` after the `sleep()`.

Comment: @sawdust did the changes suggested by you bu then even unable to write the first message ...i guess some other problem..why everything is working fine with small delays (2-5 seconds) ??

Comment: with small delays the application runs smooth for hours ..but when delay is increased it gets hung after 2-3 messages cycles..then no response from fd

Comment: Update your question by appending the revised code.  We can't guess what is going on with unseen code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Aside from the numerous coding/port configuration errors, 
as mentioned in the comments.  
I suspect the root of the problem is 
improper handling of the external device.

Perhaps the external device goes to sleep/hangs if not queried often enough.

The external device may/perhaps only respond to a status request 
when 'it' is ready
if so, then there should be no need to invoke sleep() 
as the select() will handle the
timing of the response from the external device.

A technique that will handle incoming data bytes, 
as they become available, 
is to use 'select()' to alert the program when data is available.  
then use a 'read()' of only one char at a time, 
with the read in a loop, 

Note: this usually means three loops:
the pseudo code would be: (note: this is not well structured code)

configure the I/O port
loop1:
    invoke sleep(x) // as mentioned above, this might not be necessary
    invoke write( STATUS ) on the output stream
    set byteCount = 0

    loop2:
        invoke select() on the input stream

        loop3:
            invoke a non-blocking read( a byte )
            if read successful, 
                incr byteCount 
                save byte into an array of bytes
                if enough bytes read, (in this case, 10 bytes)
                    perform any processing on the bytes read
                    goto loop1:
                endif
            else 
                handle any error
                goto loop3:
            endif
        end loop3:
   end loop2:
end loop1:
```